# Cannot access Database from Broadcast receiver class android

Tags: android, database, broadcast

I can Access Database function from my Activity and it works fine. But when I use the same in Broadcast receiver class it fails and gives me default value of cursor ,And my logcat shows this:

> close() was never explicitly called on database
>   DatabaseObjectNotCloseException

I have also done

```
db = context.openOrCreateDatabase("blitz.db", 0, null);    
dh=new DataHelper(context);
```

and passed the context of `onReceiver` method to `DataHelper` Class.
It shows error on this line

```
OpenHelper openhelper=new OpenHelper(this.context);
this.db=openhelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong

Comment: close() was never explicitly called on database DatabaseObjectNotCloseException means you had not closed the database object after you had first created it in some of activity class. Call db.close() in that first

Comment: I have done that but still the problem is persistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

always close the database when you finished your database work,

for simplicity create following method in your databaseHandler class ,

```
public void Open_DB(SQLiteDatabase db){
   return this.getWritableDatabase();
    } 

public void Close_DB(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.close();
    }
```

and use this methods in your activity or service as,

```
OpenHelper openhelper=new OpenHelper(getApplicationContext());
 SQLiteDatabase db=openhelper.Open_DB(db)
openhelper.some_Operation(db);
db.Close_DB(db);
```

or you can open and close the database in your single mehod(which is in your database handler class) as

```
public void deleteRecord(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_REMINDER, REMINDER_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id)});
        db.close();
    }
```

and call this method from your activity as,

```
public void Delete_A_Reminder(String id){
     DatabaseHandler mydb=new DatabaseHandler1(getApplicationContext());
     mydb.deleteRcord(id);
 }
```

In general,if u want to open an window of your house which is already open before then you have to close it and again open it,in the same manner if your database is already opened and if you want to open it again then you have to close it first.so that you can open it again.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a BroadcastReceiver runs on the main thread, **and** has a maximum life of 10 seconds, so you shouldn't be doing anything long-running in `onReceive(...)`.

Instead you should start up a Service to execute your long running work on a worker thread. I recommend looking at `IntentService`.

Comment: Thanks for rply ,I will Try and implement IntentService But if your have some good links on it then pls post it .

Comment: The Android Training site has a comprehensive section on Services: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

Override `OnStop()` and close there

```
@Override
public void OnStop()
{
   if(db!=null)
    {
     db.close();
     }
 }
```

It should get rid out of your error.

Answer (score -1):

The Broadcast receiver is listening on a different thread to a different process. To communicate you need to use asynchronous methods. I android the best is to register a handler and use the bundle [in Intent] to communicative.